# What is the difference between Elysium, Kilik, and Edge Master?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

All three of these characters seem to be the same, but their souls are different options when creating a character. They all choose a random fighter and mimic that style during the fight. Is there any difference between these three characters?

Comment: Wasn't Kilik the guy with the stick? What happened? O.o

Comment: @RavenDreamer Apparently he's a male weapon master now. Whenever you fight him in any of the offline modes, though, he'll use the Bo Staff style (which technically belongs to Xiba now).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kilik randomly changes between all the male characters in the game. Elysium, all the female characters. Elysium also has her own critical edge attack while Kilik just does the critical edge of whichever character he is at that time. Edgemaster is all of the characters, male and female.